# How would a CIA program to investigate the truth of religion work?

Tags: alternate-history, religion, intelligence, united-states, espionage

I'm developing a story in which the CIA has investigated the truth of religion.  In real life, during the Cold War the CIA investigated things like aliens, psychic powers, etc.  That’s because if these things were real, they would have national security implications, like they could pose threats to the US or the US government could use them against other countries.

So I don’t think it’s too far-fetched that the CIA might have tried to investigate which religion is true.  After all, a lot of the CIA rank and file and leadership in those days were devout Christians, believing in God and Angels and Demons and so on.  So it’s plausible that the CIA might have wanted to figure out what implications such supernatural entities had for the natural security of the United States, as a first step investigating what supernatural entities actually exist.

My question is, how would a Cold War-era CIA program to determine the true religion plausibly work? What methods would they employ, and how might they succeed in identifying the true religion?